# jquery loop each first td in every row

Tags: jquery, each

I have the following jquery that adds a onclick to every image within a table

```
$("#listtable tr td img").each(
    function(intIndex) {
        $(this).click(function() {
          $(this).load("/Admin/ChangeIdeaStatus/" + $(this).attr('rel'));
        });
    }
);
```

This works ok, however I would like to modify it so that only an image in the first TD of every row in the table gets the onclick event.

I have tried the following, but it does not work

```
$("#listtable tr td:first img").each(
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, using the [:first-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```
$("#listtable tr td:first-child img").click(function() {
  $(this).load("/Admin/ChangeIdeaStatus/" + $(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could set a .class or #id attribute to the first image of every row and then just select that element to have an onclick event. This might be faster than for-looping if you have a large set.

so `$(".firstImageOfTr").each( ...`